# Text slider with prompt effect web

Tags: javascript, html, css

I m making portfolio web page.  Add textview with prompt effect as like below link.
https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/DevFolio

> index.html

```
<p class="intro-subtitle"><span class="text-slider-items">Web Developer,Frontend Developer,HTML CSS Bootstrap, Android Developer, JAVA Kotlin</span><strong class="text-slider"></strong></p>
```

> main.js

```
if ($('text-slider').length == 1) {
    var typed_strings = $('text-slider-items').text();
    var typed = new Typed('text-slider', {
      strings: typed_strings.split(','),
      typeSpeed: 80,
      loop: true,
      backDelay: 1100,
      backSpeed: 30
    });
  }
```

But it doesn't work and stopped only one word. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
  if ($('.text-slider').length == 1) {
    var typed_strings = $('.text-slider-items').text();
    var typed = new Typed('.text-slider', {
      strings: typed_strings.split(','),
      typeSpeed: 80,
      loop: true,
      backDelay: 1100,
      backSpeed: 30
    });
  }
```

You have to add "." to (main.js) call DOm "class" (index.js).